# How to implement IDialogService correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Assume the following, simplified scenario:

```
//Model:
public class SessionModel: ObservableObject {
    public bool IsChecked; // IPropertyChanged is implemented
}  
//ViewModel:
public class SessionViewModel: ViewModel {
    public IDialogService DialogService {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<SessionModel> Items; // IPropertyChanged is implemented

    public async Task DownloadFromUsbDevice() {
        await = Task.Run(() => DownloadFromUsbDevice());
    }
    private void DownloadFromUsbDevice() {
        // Get all checked items. If result is empty, show a message. If an error occurs, show error message
    }
}  
// Simple IDialogService...
public interface IDialogService
{
    void ShowMessage(string message);
}
```

My first idea was, that the View of the ViewModel should implement this... This is possible, but requires me to manually assign the View to the ViewModel property in the views constructor...

```
//DialogService:
public class MainWindow: Window, IDialogService
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel.DialogService = this;
    }
    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show(this, message, string.Empty, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

Then i read that most of this services seems to be implemented standalone... But for modal dialogs and thread-safe-access i would need the Window/Dispatcher of the targeted view... So I would have to register the interface and its implementation to the SimpleIoc. Then i have to create the instance in the view constructor using a key that is specific to this View/ViewModel and assign the Window.

```
//DialogService:
public class StandaloneDialogService: IDialogService
{
    public Window Parent { get; set; }
    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show(Parent, message, string.Empty, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}  
//ServiceLocator:
public class Locator
{
    public Locator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogService, StandaloneDialogService>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SessionViewModel>();
    }

    public SessionViewModel Session => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<Session>();
}  
//View:
public class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IDialogService>("x").Parent = this;
    }
}  
//ViewModel:
public class SessionViewModel: ViewModel {
    public IDialogService DialogService => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IDialogService>("x");
    public ObservableCollection<SessionModel> Items; // IPropertyChanged is implemented

    public async Task DownloadFromUsbDevice()
    {
        await = Task.Run(() => DownloadFromUsbDevice());
    }
    private void DownloadFromUsbDevice()
    {
        // Get all checked items. If result is empty, show a message. If an error occurs, show error message
    }
}
```

Long story short... Is one of those two the right way to show (modal/non-modal) messages from a worker-function of the ViewModel? Are there better solutions? Or am I completly wrong?

Comment: There is no "right way." There rarely is in software development. Both don't violate the pattern (if that's important to you, but even then, *the pattern exists to serve us, we don't serve the pattern*), so use whatever feels better to you, or is more maintainable/discoverable/etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks. As you might guess I am new to WPF/MVVM and I saw all those during my research. Thats the reason I am asking since there might be known disadvantages of this approaches. So we can sum up that none of those is obsolete and none has an successor. Then I think we can flag this also as 'opinion based'?

Comment: Don't worry too much about it. But definitely, in future, stick with the practical issues you're facing.  Don't fall into the belly-gazing trap we often do when faced with something new.